# Get Maximum key.value pair from object without for loop

Tags: javascript, object, max

```
var obj={'one':1,'two':50,'three':75,'four':12}
```

This is object from which i want the output as 'three':75, this is key value pair for maximum value in object.
My constraint is not to use for loop and any library.
Is it possible??

Comment: that's not possible, unless you have access to the item when the values are being inserted to the object and then you can keep a local maximum at all time. but otherwise that's not possible

Comment: you must loop through the item

Comment: That's possible, but not the best/reliable way. [Math.max.apply(Math.max, JSON.stringify(obj).match(/\d+/g));](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/cc90uctu/)

Comment: What about a `while` loop?

Comment: **No library** means you're not supposed to use any inbuilt functions also?

Comment: No library means external library e:g jquery,underscore etc

Answer (score 4):

By the way I found another solution but it also uses loop.

```
var obj = {'one': 1, 'two': 50, 'three': 75, 'four': 12};

var maxKey = Object.keys(obj).sort(function (a, b) {
  return obj[a] < obj[b];
})[0];

var result = {};
result[maxKey] = obj[maxKey];
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution with loop.

```
var obj = {'one':1,'two':50,'three':75,'four':12} ; 

var maxKey = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function (prev, next){ 
                 return obj[prev] > obj[next] ? prev : next; 
             });

var result = {};
result[maxKey] = obj[maxKey];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: But that is precisely a loop.

Comment: @torazaburo, the OP specifically requested no `for` loops.

Comment: But the problem here is that only the value is being output, not the key _and_ value.

Comment: All above solutions also use map..which  is again a loop.but this solution seems good to me rather than upper ones.

Comment: @Optimus - it is now since Isa changed it yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps achieve this if you were willing to change your data structure around a bit. Instead of an object have an array of objects, and then use `filter` to grab the object based on the maximum value:

```
var arr = [
    { key: 'one', value: 1 },
    { key: 'two', value: 50 },
    { key: 'three', value: 75 },
    { key: 'four', value: 12 }
];

var max = Math.max.apply(null, arr.map(function (el) {
  return el.value;
}));

var output = arr.filter(function (el) {
  return el.value === max;
})[0];

console.log(out.key + ': ' + out.value); // three: 75
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/87th08ym/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you can make a new object form given object of this structure

```
var newObject = [
    { key: 'one', value: 1 },  // key value structure
    { key: 'two', value: 50 },
    { key: 'three', value: 75 },
    { key: 'four', value: 12 }
 ];
```

```js
var obj = {
    'one': 1,
    'two': 50,
    'three': 75,
    'four': 12
}

var newObJ = Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {
    return {
        "key": key,
            "value": obj[key]
    }
});
var max = Math.max.apply(null, newObJ.map(function (el) {
    return el.value;
}));

var output = newObJ.filter(function (el) {
    return el.value === max;
})[0];

document.write(output.key + ': ' + max);
```